# How to write a RegularExpressionValidator for a 10 Digits mobile number?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-validators

I am a new ASP.NET Webforms developer and I am struggling right now with validating the TextBox control that asks for a mobile phone number. There is only one format used when entering a phone number which is

> 05# ### ####

I would like to use ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator control with this TextBox and I need to a regular expression that matches the preceding expressions. The regular expression should validate the entered number against the following rules:

1. The preceding format
2. The number must start with 05
3. The number must be of 10 digits only

So **how can I write a regular expression (or ValidationExpression) property for this ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator control?**

Here's a snippet of my work:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneNew" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="966 ## ### ####"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPhoneNew" runat="server"
                                            ControlToValidate="txtPhoneNew" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid mobile phone number"
                                            ValidationExpression="[0-9]{10}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Maybe something like "05\d\s\d{3}\s\d{4}"?  Should match 05# ### ####.

Answer (score 0):

as Tim stated, and per your example the regular expression you need is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneNew" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="966 ## ### ####"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPhoneNew" runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtPhoneNew" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid mobile phone number"
                                        ValidationExpression="^05\d{3}\s\d{4}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneNew"  MaxLength="10" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>

   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"  
  runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhoneNew"
  ErrorMessage="enter valid phone" ValidationExpression="^05[0-9]{8}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```